# C# HttpResponse different than Fiddler

Tags: c#, http, fiddler

I want to parse a several webpages for a home project. Usualy I use `c#` `HttpWebRequest` and `HttpWebResponse` and its work well. However, for some reason, I don't have the same data in my `HttpWebResponse` than in `fiddler` for the same request. I do use the `gzip` compression `(rq.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip)` otherwise there is nothing special. I think the webpage i want to parse has some `ajax` and `telerik` (rad) call. But why I have the full page (800 lines) in `fiddler` and partial page (300 lines) in my `C#` App.

Any idea? clue?

Comment: What you see in the HttpWebResponse, should be the same as fiddler (if you are looking at just a single fiddler session), if you sent identical requests to the server.  Are you sending the user agent, and any cookies you might be sending when you make the request in the browser?  Can you add some screen shots and point out the differences?

Comment: It's hard to add useful screenshoot. I checked the call in fiddler executed by my application (not the one from a web browser). If I compare the content of my C# string and the fiddler textview tab, I don't have the same information. I tought it was the decompression, but without gzip I cannot read the stream.

Comment: The raw bytes of your HttpWebResponse, and the raw bytes streamed through fiddler would be identical, unless you uncovered a bug in fiddler, but that's unlikely.  Do you mind sharing the url you are requesting from your application?

Comment: http://www.ville.quebec.qc.ca/citoyens/taxes_evaluation/evaluation_fonciere/role/index.aspx?idfid=100000

Comment: Can you provide an example of something that you are seeing in the fiddler response that you are NOT seeing in your httpwebresponse?

Comment: I've just tried it at work and I got the good result. I don't know why it's working here and not at home.. I'll try it at home with the little code snippet I just did. Two evenings on this issue and it's working here in 2 minutes..

Comment: I'm updating my VS to update 3 at home because when I run the same test application on my home computer (win10 + VS2015 Community), I do not get the same result as my work laptop (win 8.1 + VS2013 Ultimate). sick..

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a stab at this one.

In code, you don't get the complete response, because it doesn't render all the Javascript and other linked resources. With fiddler you are seeing the full response in it's entirely.

Now what you can do is use a headless browser, their are a few of them selenium, Phanthomjs. They have the ability to wait until the entire page is rendered, you can also see the full stack trace which you can't do in C# the way you are using it.

They are available through NuGet

Comment: I'll try it. I've tried with HtmlAgilityPack but I got the same result.

Comment: HTMLAgilityPack isn't a headless browser (It just takes what you pass into it)

Answer (score 0):

OK, it's turn out that I updated my VS2015 with the latest version (update 3) and I get the good result (full page, identical as my Fiddler response).. I don't why, not even sure if it's not an reboot issue.. Same code..same .net framework..
anyway.. issue solved.